# Use of unresolved identifier 'GMSPlacesClient' after updating from GoogleMaps SDK for IOS to GooglePlaces SDK for IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places

I am using the GoogleMaps SDK for places in my app (using essentialy the Autocomplete feature) & I saw that its now possible to use only GooglePlaces SDK.

(the GoogleMaps SDK has a big size -130MB in my .ipa file)
[migration link here](https://developers.google.com/places/migrate-to-v2)

I followed the instructions but I am now getting a lot of 'Use of unresolved identifier' like GMSPlaceClients ,CLLocationDegrees or  GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController  althought they suppose to be in the GooglePlaces SDK.

Any ideas what am I missing ?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: after pod install in terminal :

[image: pod versions]

Comment: are you installing new versions ?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar , Hi you can  see my edit

Answer (score 0):

The class have changed.

Use : `GoogleAPI.placeAutocomplete(...)`

Comment: can u be more specific? Im working with the official doc [https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference ]